# Does python code using boost python in cpp make dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: python, c++, memory-leaks, boost-python

In my code, python grammar is written in Cpp code using boost python.
It works well. But I didn't fully understand how it increase object size.
Even, I couldn't prove inner code.
So I worry about memory leak.
Because real code is very huge, system will be able to die.
Below code is simple example which same algorithm applied.
Could anyone tell me that this code make memory leak or how it increase object size?

```
using namespace boost::python;
dict get_name(){
    int i;
    dict school;
    list class1;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        class1.append(student[i]);
    }
school["class1"] = class1;
return school;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might or might not leak depending of the held type of whatever `student` is mapping. But otherwise, no, you should not have to worry about a leak because the objects are wrapped by Python which will delete them whenever they are no longer referenced.